# How to store temporary values/objects per session in iOS app

Tags: ios, storage, temporary-objects

So I've got a hybrid e-commerce iOS app that I'm working on, and I need to store multiple string / array values temporarily for the duration of the checkout process. If the user leaves the checkout process, I want these values either deleted or reset. Otherwise, at periods of time during the checkout process I want to be able to retrieve these values and use them.

What's the best way to achieve this? Core Data seems a little more permanent than I'm looking for, but it might be the right way to go. I can always store stuff in there and delete it when the user leaves the checkout process, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it, basically.

A note about the hybrid part:

- When the user clicks "checkout", we launch a WebView and the checkout process continues there.
- I have a data retrieval class (instantiated via a JS bridge) that retrieves some data, but the class goes out of memory basically as soon as it's done retrieving data
- I need to access said data from the javascript in multiple separate parts, after the data retrieval class has gone out of memory

So, taking that into consideration, where is the best place for me to store the data that is retrieved by the data retrieval class? Sample code, of course, is always welcome :). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data you're retrieving from WebView is key-value pairs, you need not set up Core data for that. You can simply use NSUserDefaults to store the data. You can save settings and properties related to application or user data using NSUserDefaults. The values will get saved for the entire scope of your application but you can reset the values once you're done reading those values in Checkout process.

Here is how you save data using NSUserDefaults -

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

You can use the following code to retrieve data -

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *firstName = [defaults objectForKey:@"firstName"];
```

Comment: Got it. So I'd definitely need to reset these values manually, correct? Another idea I had was to store this information in static variables in the data retrieval class, so when it gets pulled back up again it has them in memory vs. having to retrieve them again.

Comment: You could reset the values of the keys in NSUserDefaults only when you need to use the same variable again. But storing values in static variables will also do the job. The values will remain in memory.

Comment: Good enough for me. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Is there any other way that would persist object into memory, but not saved into permanent storage (like here), especially for large objects? AFAIK this method converts to base64, which is good enough, but not for large objects.